# div stops to strech after a certain number of lines in a child div

Tags: html, css

```
<img id='imgT' src="...">

    <div id="divL"></div>
    <div id="divR">
        <div id='chapter'>
            aaaaaaaaa<br>
            aaaaaaaaa<br>
            aaaaaaaaa<br>
            aaaaaaaaa<br>
            .....
            .....
    </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
html { height: 100%; }
body{
    height: 100%;
    max-width:1024px;
}
#imgT{
    width:100%;
    border:thin solid blue;
    display:block;
}
#divL{
    width:20%;
    height: 100%;
    background:#008080;
    float:left;
}
#divR{
    width:80%;
    height: 100%;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

After a certain number of lines in div `chapter` - `divL` and `divR` stop to stretch to the height of 100% !?

You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NPjZe/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css tables.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NPjZe/9/)**

```
.wpr
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#divL{
    width:20%;
    height: 100%;
    background:#008080;

    display:table-cell;
}
#divR{
    width:80%;
    height: 100%;
    background:blue;

    display:table-cell;
}
```